# c# variable listview items in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a WPF ListView:

```
<ListView Margin="10,10,0,10" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="listViewConfigItems" MinHeight="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
//hard coded columns
</ListView>
```

And I need to add items to this list programmatic and now also variable (read from an xml configuration file)

I used to populate items to the list like this:

```
 //Populate items to listView
foreach (var obj in objectList)
{
 myWindow.listViewConfigItems.Items.Add(new MyItem
            {
                DisplayName = obj.DisplayName,                   
                Title = obj.Title,
                Description = obj.Description
             });
}

 //....//

 internal class MyItem
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

This works fine, the items are placed on the list and mapped to the right columns. Now my challenge is to NOT hardcode those properties, but be able to make my own in the XML file. I guess this would require that the class MyItem would be dynamic in some way.

I managed to make the columns populate automatic like this (semi-pseudo):

```
 foreach (var conf in GetColumnConfiguration())
{
        {
           GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn()
            {
                Header = GetHeaderDisplayName(),
                DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(GetBindingName())


            };
 }
```

But I'm not sure how to make a similar approach to add Items on the ListView.

I am using .NET 3.5. The application cannot use .NET 4 or above, but I'm able to install custom assemblies if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by creating the class at run-time using reflection, inspired by this post:
http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2008/06/Create-you-own-new-Type-and-use-it-on-run-time-(C).aspx

Then I am able to handle variable properties from users.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe wanna use the XmlDataProvider (just google it) and set the `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`

Comment: Thanks, but it's not important where the data comes from. I need a way to add variable data to my listview. I can only get it to work by making properties on my Myitem class that matches the displaymember bindings in the header, but in this case I have no idea what the bindings and the properties will be beforehand (it's variable) so I don't know the names of my properties.

Comment: Just read on it, maybe this could work. But my problem is that the object data is not from XML-files, but from Enterprisemanagement objects. The xml file is actually a Management pack, so the format needs to be a special way. Here I only control what properties I would like to get from those internal objects of the application.

Comment: Is that your objectList? What kind of object/class do you have in that list?

Comment: It's of type EnterpriseManagement object (SCOM project).

The problem is mainly to populate variable properties to my ListView, the only way I found is feeding it with a class, but the properties of this class is not dynamic.

If only I could do something like this:

`internal class MyItem {
propertyArray[0] {get; set}
propertyArray[1] {get; set}
...
}`

Or maybe the listview can be feeded in some other way ? 

Thanks cecilia.